# How to use "aggregate" with "project" in MongoDB query in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

Environment:

MongoDB.Driver (2.8.1);

Microsoft.NETCore.App (3.0.0-preview7-27912-14);

Language: C#

I have the following storage structure in MongoDB, in a Colletion named: "Revendas":

```
...
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd0825f92225e4f1179f3b8"),
    "Codigo" : NumberLong(0),
    "Nome" : "Revenda com dois clientes",
    "CPF" : "string",
    "CNPJ" : "string",        
    "Clientes" : [ 
        {
            "Codigo" : "1",
            "Nome" : "Primeiro cliente da revenda 5cd0825f92225e4f1179f3b8",
            "CPF" : "string",
            "CNPJ" : "string",
            "Tokens" : [ 
                {                        
                    "Token" : "bd2b0f0734b3977ebfd56b6965fbdf9bff17f1e6",
                    "Geracao" : ISODate("2019-05-03T17:27:30.678-03:00"),
                    "Revogacao" : ISODate("2019-05-03T17:28:58.858-03:00")
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            /*This is the block I need to return*/
            "Codigo" : "2",
            "Nome" : "Segundo cliente da revenda 5cd0825f92225e4f1179f3b8",
            "CPF" : "string",
            "CNPJ" : "string",
            "Tokens" : [ 
                {
                    /* This is the field where I will do the research */
                    "Token" : "671bcaf806405e5d55419746a1b320cc729558fb",
                    "Geracao" : ISODate("2019-05-06T09:29:07.928-03:00"),
                    "Revogacao" : ISODate("2022-05-06T09:29:07.928-03:00")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
...
```

I would like to search the client token collection and return only the client who answers the query.
I was able to execute the query directly in mongodb:

```
db.Revendas.aggregate([
    { $unwind :'$Clientes'},
    { $match : {'Clientes.Tokens.Token': '671bcaf806405e5d55419746a1b320cc729558fb' }},
    { 
        $project : {
            Codigo: "$Clientes.Codigo", 
            Nome : '$Clientes.Nome', 
            CNPJ : '$Clientes.CNPJ',
            CPF: '$Clientes.CPF',
            Tokens : '$Clientes.Tokens'       
        } 
    }
])
```

The previous query returns the data I need:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cd0825f92225e4f1179f3b8"),
    "Codigo" : "2",
    "Nome" : "Segundo cliente da revenda 5cd0825f92225e4f1179f3b8",
    "CNPJ" : "string",
    "CPF" : "string",
    "Tokens" : [ 
        {
            "Token" : "671bcaf806405e5d55419746a1b320cc729558fb",
            "Geracao" : ISODate("2019-05-06T09:29:07.928-03:00"),
            "Revogacao" : ISODate("2022-05-06T09:29:07.928-03:00")
        }
    ]
}
```

The question is, how do you translate this query to the C# mongodb driver?

My attempt was:

```
string tokenpesquisa = "";

var agg = Database.GetCollection<RevendaCliente>("{'Clientes.Tokens.Token': '" + tokenpesquisa + "'}").Aggregate();

var project = agg.Project(o => new {
    Codigo = o.Codigo,
    Nome = o.Nome,
    CNPJ = o.CNPJ,
    CPF = o.CPF,
    Tokens = o.Tokens
});

var result = project.ToListAsync().Result;
```

But the data is not returned as expected.

---

The following is the code snippet suggested by user @mickl that solved my problem:

```
CollRevendas = Database.GetCollection<Revenda>("Revendas");

var query = CollRevendas.Aggregate()
 .Unwind("Clientes")
 .Match(new BsonDocument() { { "Clientes.Tokens.Token", "" + tokenpesquisa + "" } })
 .Project<RevendaCliente>(new BsonDocument()
     {
        { "_id", 0 },
        { "Codigo", "$Clientes.Codigo" },
        { "Nome", "$Clientes.Nome" },
        { "CNPJ", "$Clientes.CNPJ" },
        { "CPF", "$Clientes.CPF" },
        { "Tokens", "$Clientes.Tokens" }
     });

var doc = query.First();

return doc;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic method `GetCollection<T>` takes a collection name as it's first argument. Simplest approach here is to operate on `BsonDocument` type which represents MongoDB document and can be later deserialized into your type:

```
var col = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Revendas");

var query =  col.Aggregate()
                .Unwind("Clientes")
                .Match(new BsonDocument(){ { "Clientes.Tokens.Token", "671bcaf806405e5d55419746a1b320cc729558fb" } })
                .Project(new BsonDocument()
                    {
                        { "Codigo", "$Clientes.Codigo" },
                        { "Nome", "$Clientes.Nome" },
                        { "CNPJ", "$Clientes.CNPJ" },
                        { "CPF", "$Clientes.CPF" },
                        { "Tokens", "$Clientes.Tokens" }
                    });

var doc = query.First();
```

You can also cast your aggregation result by introducing a type that represents your result:

```
public class Model
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string CNPJ { get; set; }
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public TokenModel[] Tokens { get; set; }
}

public class TokenModel
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public DateTime Geracao { get; set; }
    public DateTime Revogacao { get; set; }
}
```

and running generic version of `Project`:

```
.Project<Model>(new BsonDocument()
    {
        { "Codigo", "$Clientes.Codigo" },
        { "Nome", "$Clientes.Nome" },
        { "CNPJ", "$Clientes.CNPJ" },
        { "CPF", "$Clientes.CPF" },
        { "Tokens", "$Clientes.Tokens" }
    });
```

Comment: ! His answer was correct. Man, I don't even have words to thank you, thank you very much.
The cool thing about writing the query, as you suggested, is that we can see the query that was assembled before executing it.
I edited my question, including the code snippet that solved my situation.