# MongoDb C# projection fails after upgrade to V3

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have just upgraded the Linqprovider for MongoDb C#driver to V3:

```
var clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(Configuration.GetConnectionString(MyConnectionString));
clientSettings.LinqProvider = **LinqProvider.V3**;
```

Mostly my queries work ok but there are several I am having problems with, like this one:

```
return await _myCollection.Find(model.GetFilter())
    .Project(x => new MyModel
    {
    Id = x.Id,
....
    FirstVideoTitle = x.Videos != null && x.Videos.Any() ? x.Videos.First().Title : "",
})
```

I have also tried x.Videos.Length > 0 which also fails with the following error message:

```
  Command find failed: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing.
  MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command find failed: Executor error during find command :: caused by :: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing.
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ProcessResponse(ConnectionId connectionId, CommandMessage responseMessage)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingCommandMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.Server.ServerChannel.ExecuteProtocolAsync[TResult](IWireProtocol`1 protocol, ICoreSession session, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableReadOperationExecutor.ExecuteAsync[TResult](IRetryableReadOperation`1 operation, RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.ReadCommandOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(RetryableReadContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindOperation`1.ExecuteAsync(IReadBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteReadOperationAsync[TResult](IReadBinding binding, IReadOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

How can I make this work using the MongoDb C# driver? This used to work fine in LinqProvider.V2

Comment: try to query it via `Aggregate`  and $match and $project stages

Comment: I am trying to use the C# driver

Comment: yes, and I suggest to use it there https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.22/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_Aggregate__1_1.htm

Comment: How do you use this in a projection?

Comment: `Aggregate` works very close to how `Find` works with the difference that aggregate supports much more complex queries. See for example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663598/how-to-use-aggregate-with-project-in-mongodb-query-in-c

Comment: If I downgrade to LinqProvider.V2, my code works as is and I don't have to rewrite it!

Comment: The new linq provider in rare cases may change logic in some cases for different reasons, this is what happened here as I can see.

Comment: ok, so for queries where I look at an array in a project claue I need to rewrite the code using aggregate?